# iterate on non zero columns to get cost

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data with weekly sale quantity, amount and cost and i want to find out the cost price for each product row by dividing the weekly quantity sold with the cost, however it is possible that the latest row has zero values, so i wish to skip it i it has zero value and use the previous week to calculate for the cost or until it finds a non zero values and computes the item cost(wkx_cost/wkx_amount) . Also note that product price may have changed over the weeks so i need the cost from the latest week but if not available try calcuating item cost price from the previous week.

```
    df2 = pd.DataFrame([
{'product':'iphone11', 'wk1_qty':2, 'wk1_amount':100,
    'wk1_cost':60, 'wk2_qty':3, 'wk2_amount':150,
    'wk2_cost':90, 'wk3_qty':0, 'wk3_amount':0,
    'wk3_cost':0, 'wk4_qty':5, 'wk4_amount':300,
    'wk4_cost':60, 'wk5_qty':0, 'wk5_amount':0,
    'wk5_cost':0}, {'product':'acer laptop', 'wk1_qty':3, 'wk1_amount':300,
    'wk1_cost':210, 'wk2_qty':3, 'wk2_amount':300,
    'wk2_cost':210, 'wk3_qty':0, 'wk3_amount':0,
    'wk3_cost':0, 'wk4_qty':5, 'wk4_amount':550,
    'wk4_cost':375, 'wk5_qty':5, 'wk5_amount':500,
    'wk5_cost':375}])
```

What result should look like

```
    df2 = pd.DataFrame([
{'product':'iphone11', 'wk1_qty':2, 'wk1_amount':100,
    'wk1_cost':60, 'wk2_qty':3, 'wk2_amount':150,
    'wk2_cost':90, 'wk3_qty':0, 'wk3_amount':0,
    'wk3_cost':0, 'wk4_qty':5, 'wk4_amount':300,
    'wk4_cost':160, 'wk5_qty':0, 'wk5_amount':0,
    'wk5_cost':0, 'product_price':32}, {'product':'acer laptop', 'wk1_qty':3, 'wk1_amount':300,
    'wk1_cost':210, 'wk2_qty':3, 'wk2_amount':300,
    'wk2_cost':210, 'wk3_qty':0, 'wk3_amount':0,
    'wk3_cost':0, 'wk4_qty':5, 'wk4_amount':550,
    'wk4_cost':375, 'wk5_qty':5, 'wk5_amount':500,
    'wk5_cost':375, 'product_price':75}])
```

Comment: Can you show how you get to the product price 32 for iPhone11?

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes it was gotten by dividing the latest week non-zero cost by its quantity wk4_cost/wk4_qty 160/5.

Comment: Ok you described the expected behavior. Where are you struggling at and what is your specific programming question? Please show your attempts.

Comment: i amnot entirely sure how to approach it, i am still reading up how to use lambda functions to iterate over rows of columns.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises when there is a division by zero. So, to short-cut that (or deal with it) would could try this:

```
try:
    Product_price = wk_cost/wk_qty
except ZeroDivisionError:
    Product_price = 0
```

Comment: i need just one column to hold the latest item price, how do i apply this on a jupyter notebook